# How to access complete object from a select field in react js

Tags: reactjs, select

I'm working on a form in which we have a customer field which is a drop down and currency field which is again a drop down field. I have to set the values of the other fields based on the selected customer. But i'm not getting how to do it.

I tried to use the `customerObj` and set the value for the currency option also, but it didn't work.

This is my complete component code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Links from './Links.jsx';
import style from './app.css';

import axios from 'axios';

class AddNewProject extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {clients: [],
                      project : {
                          client : '',
                          currency : ''
                      }
                     };
        this.getClients = this.getClients.bind(this);
        this.handleUserInput = this.handleUserInput.bind(this);
    }
  // on load od component this method will be called.
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getClients();
    }

    // Api call for fetching the customers
    getClients(){
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:6060/account/getAll',
        }).then(response => {
                console.log('response:',response.data.data);
                this.setState({
                    clients: response.data.data
                })
            this.state.clients = response.data.data;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('Error fetching and parsing data', error);
                this.setState({
                    clients: []
                })
            });
        console.log(this.state.clients);
    }

    // on change handler
    handleUserInput(e){
        const value = e.target.value;
        const name = e.target.name;
        let {project} = this.state;
        // here i want to set the value for the currency drop down also
        project.client = value;
        this.setState({
            project
        })
    }

    render() {

        // creating options for customer/client
        var customerOptions = this.state.clients.map(function(customerObj ,index) {
            return (
                <option key={index+1} value={customerObj} >{customerObj.name}</option>
            );
        }.bind(this));

        // creating currency options
        var currencies = [{value: "USD"}, {value: "INR"}]

        var currencyOptions = currencies.map(function(currencyObj ,index) {
            return (
                <option key={index+1} value={currencyObj.value} >{currencyObj.value}</option>
            );
        }.bind(this));

      return (
        <div>
            <Links activeTabName="tab3"></Links>
            <div className="container">
                <div className = "row col-md-4">
                    <h1>Add New Project...</h1>
                </div>
                <div className = "row col-md-4">
                </div>
                <div className = "row col-md-4">
                </div>
                <hr style = {{'clear':'both'}}>
                </hr>
                <form id = "addEmployeeForm" className = {style.fontClass} >
                    <div className = "form-group row col-md-6">
                        <div className = "col-sm-4">
                            <label className="col-form-label">Customer
                                <sup className = {style.redSup}>*</sup>: 
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className = "col-sm-6">
                            <select name="client" value = {this.state.project.client} onChange={this.handleUserInput}>
                                <option value="">Select Customer</option>
                                {customerOptions}
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className = "form-group row col-md-6">
                        <div className = "col-sm-4">
                            <label className="col-form-label">Currency
                                <sup className = {style.redSup}>*</sup>: 
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div className = "col-sm-6">
                            <select name="currency" value = {this.state.project.currency} onChange={this.handleUserInput}>
                                <option value="">Select Currency</option>
                                {currencyOptions}
                                </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

export default AddNewProject;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `value` in the `options` use `index` for `customerOptions`

```
var customerOptions = this.state.clients.map(function(customerObj ,index) {
            return (
                <option key={index+1} value={index} >{customerObj.name}</option>
            );
        }.bind(this));
```

JS :

```
 handleUserInput(e){
        // will give selected customer
        let selectedCustomer = this.state.clients[event.target.value];

        //script to get the currency
        let selectedCurrency = ..
        this.setState({project.currency:selectedCurrency});
    }
```

DEMO : https://codesandbox.io/s/z081rpqj4

Comment: Thanks bro, the logic to use index as the value from select is worked for me.